# Can I cancel a 'pending edit'

Tags: feature-request, support, review, edits, suggested-edits

I suggested edits on a few questions/answers and they are now pending. As the Stack Overflow site only allows **5** pending edits, I would like to know if it is possible to cancel any such edits in order to suggest more substantial ones?

[image: screenshot of pending edits]

In my particular case, I have two pending edits that are code indentation fixes and I would like to cancel them in order to propose other, more judicious, edits.

This would be especially useful as I have pending edits that are two days old.

Comment: I don't think you can cancel them. You have to wait until they are reviewed.